# Renderscript via the support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

Seems to me that android has an android.support.v8 package that contains Renderscript support. The thing is, this doesn't seem documented anywhere - [the support library docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) don't say anything about a v8 package, just v4 and v13.

Is that package supported on all devices with API level 8 and above and can it be safely used in production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PSA for Googlers: [RenderScript is now part of the Android Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html). You can use it on Android 2.2+.

Comment: True, thanks for updating the answers. Mandatory I/O talk - https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/331954522

Comment: Pick support v8 from "sdk\build-tools\APILEVEL\renderscript\lib\renderscript-v8.jar"  where api level is above 18

Answer (score 9):

Its not yet production quality.

Comment: Thank you, didn't expect a response by an actual Googler. I'll keep an eye out for when it's finally released.

Comment: Are there any sample working Renderscript implementations that use the v8 code?

Answer (score 8):

My Android tools contain the files:

```
./build-tools/18.1.0/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar
./build-tools/18.1.1/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar
```

Putting them in the libs/ directory of your project will result in a working build in Eclipse and with ant.

Answer (score 3):

I have eclipse,  android sdk tools 22.6.3, android platform tools 19.0.1 and I set both of these projects API 19 android 4.4.2.

I was able to compile and run hellocompute(from the samples of android 19) and wants to change it to android support v8 things.

following steps works for me:

1.set android build target to 4.4.2 api 19.

2.add "rendersrcipt-v8.jar" to libraries in android build path

3.in project.properties set things like

```
"target=android-19
 renderscript.target=19
 renderscript.support.mode=true
 sdk.buildtools=19.0.3"
```

4.Comment out the following import lines:

```
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
```

and import

```
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;
```

5.clean the project and rebuild.

Comment: Pick support v8 from "sdk\build-tools\APILEVEL\renderscript\lib\renderscript-v8.jar"  where api level is above 18