# Where I can find android-support-v8.jar file to be able to use Render Script in my application

Tags: android, imageview, android-support-library, blur, renderscript

I need to download `android-support-v8.jar` as I have to use `blur effect` for `Imageview` in my `android application.`

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879439/renderscript-via-the-support-library

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle, try below in your **build.gradle**, after this is resolved, you can use **android-support-v8.jar** anywhere in your project

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```